# Windows Boot disk doesnt boot in Gcloud Vm Instances

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, boot, g-suite

I'm trying to boot differents physical disk in gcloud. So the complete process is:

I dd the physical disk in linux (with a bs of 1G). Later i compressed in format tar.gz (with format=oldgnu, like gcloud want).

I uploaded that file in a google cloud bucket and later with gcloud compute, i converted that image.tar.gz in a gcloud image to boot a vm instance.

The problem is when i'm trying to boot that instance this error appears:

`Booting from Hard Disk 0... Boot failed: not a bootable disk`

I have tried to make a external disk with that image. I converted that image in a disk, and all my files are in there. All the partitions and boot partitions in there are in good state.

I read the documentation in gcloud for how to make the correct image, and how gcloud computes images. The docu about how windows boot in the vm is... unclear.

There is a exceptional way to boot windows in gcloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is gcloud cant boot uefi systems.

I did the same process in AWS and the EC2 Image Builder have a debug which specify that there some EC2 machine that could not boot EUFI systems and there are some that will do.

I solve this problem simply booting the so in a t3 machine of aws.